# Can 'should' be used in past tense?

Tags: past-tense, should

In the second line of the text, taken from 'Harry Potter',

" Yes,but it took a great deal of skilled Legilimency to coax it out of him.' said Dumbledore, 'and why **should** everybody delve further into Morfins mind when he had already confessed to the crime?"

What's the meaning of **should** here?

Can we use *should* in past sentences as well?

[image: context from Harry Potter]

Comment: How do you put "should have been" into that sentence? Could you [edit your question](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/537953/edit) to include the sentence you think JK Rowling should have written here? Also, please type out the relevant quote from the book as images aren't accessible.

Comment: Although referring to a particular incident in the past, Dumbledore uses _should_ as a general question  - 'Why would anyone want to delve into his mind?"

Comment: "Should" *is* the past tense. Always. The present tense is "shall".

Comment: @kate Bunting So does it mean 'should' is sometimes interchangeable with 'would, if used to ask a general question?  -Tripti1234

Comment: In this context, yes. By 'a general question', I meant that he is speculating about all possible reasons for 'delving into Morfin's mind'.

Comment: Thank you for the help:)